# Error:return type specified for 'operator std::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}'

Tags: c++, string, eclipse, operator-overloading

What could be the possible cause and solution of the error ??

In .h file

```
std::string operator std::string();
```

In .c file `X` is some `int` variable 
and `Y` is a `char`

```
string ClassName::operator string()
{
    string temp;

    temp = X + Y;

    return temp;

}
```

Answer (score 7):

The name of a conversion operator is it's return type.  That means you don't specify one for them.  That would give you

```
operator std::string();
```

for the declaration and the definition would be

```
ClassName::operator string()
{
    string temp;

    temp = X + Y;

    return temp;

}
```

---

Also note that you while `temp = X + Y;` will compile, what it will do is give you some character that is `X` places along in the character table.  If you want `123 + a` to be `123a` then you need `temp = std::to_string(X) + Y;`